Multiple Azure function app using a single virtual network integration
I have a VNET on Azure with a VPN S2S connection where I download data from the client. I have a whitelisted subnet with a small IP range.
We have started using Function Apps and there is a problem because a particular Function App can use vnet-integration but only if it is a new subnet not used by anything else.
Wanting to have test/dev/prod variants I would have to create more subnets, ask for them to be whitelisted - which will not be possible.
I found an article on using NAT for a public IP address but it doesn't work for an internal network.
How can I use one subnet (vnet-integration) in several different function app or how to nat your traffic from different subnets to as one specific address?

Due to the Networking limitations, You need to have one dedicated Subnet per Function App, You can create a V-Net Hub architecture where multiple V-Nets are connected via V-Net Peering.
My Silicon Function with Vnet and subnet connected:-

My Valley Function with Vnet and subnet connected:-

Add the V-Net Peering between siliconvnet and valleyvnet5:-

Once you enable peering both networks and its underlying resources can communicate with each other. Thus if Silicon Function can connect to Valley Function and perform tasks.
